# Create cylinder with different bases

Tags: objects, transforms

I need to create cyllinder with 16 vertices on top but only 4 vertices on bottom plane. Im trying to merge faces and dissolve edges, but the resulting object looks deformed, cut out.

Comment: Try to triangulate the mesh (ctrl + T in edit mode), presuming you have regularly dissolved the vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### recreating triangles

The simplest way I can think of for merging a square with a 16-gon is connecting each of the square's vertices to the 4 closest 16-gon vertices, then creating the 4 remaining triangles

[image]

(*Select*, *Select*, *Select*, <kbd>F</kbd>)

#### merging vertices

Otherwise, you can start from a 16-cylinder and merge 4 vertices at the time:

[image]

(*Select* 4, <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>, repeat 4 times, then <kbd>W</kbd> and "Remove doubles").

This will create 4 4-edged faces instead of only triangles.

---

These are the results (first method left, second method right):

[image]

which are definitely "cut out" (you are cutting 75% of the vertices after all), but not deformed.

Note: before attempting any smooth shading, an *Edge split* modifier is advised!

Answer (score 7):

My approach would be to use a circle with 16 vertices, and one with 4 vertices.

Add both in while in *edit mode* so they are part of the same object,and then use [*bridge edge loops*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edge/bridge_edge_loops.html?#bridge-edge-loops) operator  with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd>

You can then quad cap the 16 vert side with [*grid fill*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/face/grid_fill.html?#grid-fill) , ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> then <kbd>G</kbd> )and fill the quad with <kbd>F</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An alternative method:

- Starting from a cylinder
- Select the upper ring
- Checker deselect (so that 1/2 vertices stay selected)
- Dissolve vertices
- Checker deselect again
- Dissolve vertices

If wanted, triangulate using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>.

[image]