# Anyone know a technique for blending these two smoothly? It's a sword handle attaching to guard

Tags: modeling, topology

[image: These can be seperate or merged, whatever you think is best.]

[image: This is my goal! How shall I go about this?]

I tried bridging, it kind of works but ruins the normals, I also tried extruding and the "to sphere" function. That was even worse.

Thanks.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75213/i-need-to-turn-one-side-of-a-cylinder-into-a-square-a-leave-the-other-side-round   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/103328/create-cylinder-with-different-bases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something like this, I would recommend a progressive reduction in the number of faces by using extrude and merge operations (Provided your starting cylinder has an even number of faces).

Start by extruding a section of the cylinder. From here, select neighboring pairs of points around the perimeter, and merge them to their midpoint by pressing <kbd>M</kbd> and selecting "at center".

[image: Merge1]

Once all the pairs are merged, extrude the bottom face and do it again.

[image: Merge2]

Do this as many times as is necessary until the bottom face only has 4 points. Note - by this point the bottom face will have "shrunk" a bit relative to the rest due to the merge operations. You may take this opportunity to scale it back until it's closer to the size of the mesh above it.

[image: Merge3]

From here, you can extrude the bottom face again, and then scale it to fit the piece you are trying to connect it to.

[image: Merge4]